# Is it necessary to wear plain dress?

Tags: women, hijab, non-mahram

Is it necessary for a woman to wear completely plain dress, I mean without any design on it,in front of non-mahram?

Comment: I wish Muslims instructed their men to also wear Islamically correct clothing instead of just focusing on the females. Many a times we have seen men wearing tight tops or pants revealing the shape of their stomachs, thighs & buttocks. It is sad that today we expect the women to be more of a Muslim than the men.

Answer (score 0):

It is not permissible to wear clothes if they are in a way that makes the person point fingers in the eyes of others or attract the attention of non-mahrams - even in the quality of wearing them. In the outer cover, conditions have been stated for the clothes: to cover the body completely, not too thin and not to be body-shaped, in terms of volume to cover the ridges and ridges of the body, not too tight and sticky, and also this dress promotes a culture of vulgarity or Do not be the culture of enemies. It means being independent yourself. In general, the clothes should not be so tight that the size and geometry of the body is specified or attract the attention of non-mahrams or point fingers.